# How to make HTTP PUT the inverse of GET?

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to tell Apache to treat a HTTP PUT as the inverse of GET. The server should store the file sent with PUT at that place, where a file would be read by a GET request containing the same location.

I found only [examples](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put) for HTTP PUT, which require CGI or PHP scripts and [mod_put](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-modules-dev/200610.mbox/%3Cc5dace480610260752x3aa3e0cdv408311920c71f3c0@mail.gmail.com%3E) seems to be dead. First I would like to avoid scripts: CGI because of [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) and PHP because of [PHP](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/PHP-PHP.html). And second even if I would try to write some CGI I am not aware of Apache's location-directory mapping in the CGI. I would not know how to map the location from the URL to a path in the file system in that way, that Apache would perform the inverse during a GET.

How to implement a HTTP PUT being exactly the inverse of a GET without any CGI or script engine?

Answer (score 2):

The apache core has the feature to handle PUT requests, but unfortunately this can only forward the request to some of its handler modules (f.e. PHP or to a cgi script).

To the feature you have, this PUT feature had to be implemented in an apache module, too. The apache modules are the same things as the java servlets or cgi scripts: they get http requests, process them, and give back the results.

Unfortunately, the apache modul with made possibly a file upload function by PUT requests, simply wasn't developed. I must mention: even you could do that, although the apache interface isn't the most beautiful I've seen, it is possible and weren't a really big work. But it wasn't done. Or the mod_put module could be re-animated. I could do this in a week, but nobody pays me to do that, or I don't have a free week for the job. Every programmer of the world said the same, if you could ask them.

There are a lot of tools/modules with very similar features in arbitrary, especially WebDAV which were very interesting to you. With them you can reach these, although they are working not by PUT, but with multiparted POST queries. And WebDAV is an overkill because it uses hard (and mostly unneeded) xml processing even for simple tasks.

Comment: WebDAV is overkill for a simple PUT and it bloats the server with all the XML processing necessary for WebDAV.

Comment: @ceving Yest, it is right. If I looked for the best solution, I revived mod_put.